# Find matching rows in a database where a column matches one entry out of a dynamic array

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a table with multiple columns in it, one of which, labeled `'ID'`, contains a unique number. I am sending a list of values to pull to a server-side php script that uses a prepared statement to make the pull. Through some research I found that I believe I am looking for `IN` inside of my statement. I get how to hardcode a list in to the statement, such as: `SELECT * FROM spotzz WHERE ID IN (465, 732, 219)` or something along those lines, but my confusion comes from the prepared statement. I need a `?` for every value I'm passing to the statement, but if the length of the list is not always the same, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically generate the prepared statement string based on how many values are in your array:

```
$values = [1,2,3,4];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM spotzz WHERE `ID` IN (" .
    // array_fill() creates an array with as many '?' as there are
    // elements in $values. implodes() glues the new array elems with a ","
    implode(',', array_fill(0,count($values),'?')) .
    ")";

echo $sql; // SELECT * FROM spotzz WHERE `ID` IN (?,?,?,?)
```